# SharePoint 2010 Library Tools Menu not displayed for some users

Tags: 2010, library, tools

I am experiencing some strange behaviour with some users on our SharePoint 2010 Enterprise. For some of them, the library tools menu is not displayed on the pages. All they can see is an empty frame. The Site actions menu works fine. The navigation menu  works fine as well, including the display of the list views.

[image]

As you can see, the javascript menu does not load.

More info:

- Happens on IE9/Win7 for some users and not for others
- Happens also on IE8/WinXP for some users and not others

What I tried:
 - Resetting the browser settings to default;
 - Adding the site to Intranet sites and then to Trusted sites.

Any help welcome.

Comment: Do you have any custom ribbon solutions? Did you try to clear cache (F12, Ctrl+R in IE)? Are there any JS errors reported by browser?

Comment: Users have edit permission to list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found it. It is because of the Compatibility View.

Special thanks to Vedran for reminding me to use the console.